# Korean language on Transparent JFrame

Tags: java, text, transparent

I have to use undecorated transparent jframe on my program.

and then JTextfield or jtable will on it.

but it makes big problem. see this jtextfield.

[image: fine one]

text on jtextfield is korean language.

and it's very readable if korean.

but if transparent applied , being like this.

[image: issued one]

can you recognize it? (text on textfield is broken? or changed..)

that's not readable even korean people.

why this issue happen?

and.. what i have to do for solve this problem.

appreciate any help.